# What is the best HM Pack Mule in Generation V?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I realize this is a slightly unconstrained question (what qualifies as best?), so let's constrain it a little.

In Generation V we've reduced the number of HMs to 6.  Now given I can only stick 4 moves on a Pokémon, let's first constrain this problem by limiting the moves to HMs 1-4 (Cut, Fly, Surf, Strength).  Now, 3 out of those 4 are physical moves, so let's prefer Pokemon with high Attack.  Finally, let's preferentially select for Pokémon we encounter earlier (rather than later) so we can take advantage of our mule of longer.

To summerize:

Best HM Pack Mule that:

1. Can use Cut, Fly, Surf, Strength
2. Has a high Attack
3. Occurs fairly early in Pokémon Black and/or White

Comment: Just as a sidenote, unlike previous generation, Gen V is much less reliant on HMs. The only HM you need to complete the game is Cut (to access the Dreamyard).

Comment: I'd *like* to recommend Samurott, since it can learn Cut, Strength, Surf, and Waterfall (which makes it very utilitarian for most exploration runs, since Fly is for use *post* exploration). However, it can only learn Strength in its final evolution (at level 36), and Strength is the second HM you'll get, which means it ends up a bit far from your early-game needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only HM you need to complete the main storyline of Black and White is cut, and this is a one-time event (you need to Cut a tree down in the Dreamyard to progress the storyline). Because of this, other HM moves only allow access to hidden items or for convenience. The main HMs people use are Surf and Fly, and Ducklett / Swanna can both learn the two moves.

Ducklett can be found as a shadow on the Driftveil Drawbridge, and Swanna on the Marvelous Bridge. (I believe you cross the Driftveil Drawbridge before even obtaining Fly or Surf.)

If you want a Pokémon that can learn Cut and Strength, Patrat is available early in the game and can learn Cut. When it evolves into Watchog, you can teach it Strength. (No Pokémon in Gen V can learn all four moves you listed.)

Answer (score 6):

[Basculin](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Basculin_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) fits 2/3 of your requirements. He has a decent attack (Base attack of 92, max attack of 311 at Level 100) and can be found relatively early (requires surf). He learns the following HMs:

- Cut
- Surf
- Waterfall
- Dive

So, he keeps his use as an HM machine after getting the rest of the HMs. Although, I believe Dive is only used in one spot.

I also have to mention the best fly user in the game: [Golurk](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Golurk_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29)

[image: Best flyer evar.]

Is there anything cooler than flying around on a golem at Mach speeds (according to Black's pokedex)?

He has a base attack of 124 (Max of 381 at Level 100). His unevolved form can be found in Dragonspiral Tower.

It learns the following HMs:

- Strength
- Fly (Only Golurk learns this one, Golett is unable to fly)
- Not an HM, but Flash can come in handy

Answer (score 1):

If you have a suitable Water-type Pokémon, such as the one I use, [Simipour](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Simipour_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), you can teach it Cut, Surf, Waterfall, and Dive.  (Note that the [elemental monkeys](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Elemental_monkeys), including [Panpour](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Panpour_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), from which Simipour evolves, can be caught at [Pinwheel Forest](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pinwheel_Forest) with a 10% chance of encountering each one in rustling grass.)  Other candidates include [Basculin](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Basculin_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) as mentioned by Rapida, and the fully-evolved starter [Samurott](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Samurott_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) as Grace Note mentioned.

For the other two HM moves, you can use [Pidove](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pidove_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) or its evolved forms for Fly and [Throh](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Throh_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) or [Sawk](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sawk_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) for Strength.  Personally, I use [Kyurem](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kyurem_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) for Fly and [Lucario](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lucario_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) for Strength (both not available until after the first game clear).

Answer (score 1):

Frillish can learn Surf, Dive, Waterfall and Flash. Not the moves you're looking for but still a good round up.

Answer (score 0):

braviary, though it evolves kinda late, at lvl 54, can learn cut, strength, and fly.

Comment: Braviary (or its basic form Rufflet) cannot be caught from the wild in Pokémon Black Version.  It is exclusive to White.